# Why does lines.map not work, but lines.take.map works, in Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, machine-learning, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and Spark.

I am practicing with the [SparkHdfsLR.scala code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/SparkHdfsLR.scala).

But I ran into a problem with this section of code:

```
60    val lines = sc.textFile(inputPath)
61    val points = lines.map(parsePoint _).cache()
62    val ITERATIONS = args(2).toInt
```

Line 61 does not work. After I change it to this:

```
60    val lines = sc.textFile(inputPath)
61    val points = lines.take(149800).map(parsePoint _)  //149800 is the total number of lines
62    val ITERATIONS = args(2).toInt
```

The error msg from the sbt run is:

```
[error] (run-main) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job failed: Task 0.0:1 failed more than 4 times
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job failed: Task 0.0:1 failed more than 4 times
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.processEvent(DAGScheduler.scala:379)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$run(DAGScheduler.scala:441)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anon$1.run(DAGScheduler.scala:149)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error] {file:/var/sdb/home/tim.tan/workspace/spark/}default-d3d73f/compile:run: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 52 s, completed Dec 20, 2013 5:42:18 PM
```

The std error of the task nodes is:

```
13/12/20 17:42:16 INFO slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler: Slf4jEventHandler started
13/12/20 17:42:16 INFO executor.StandaloneExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: akka://spark@SHXJ-H07-SDB06:38975/user/StandaloneScheduler
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO executor.StandaloneExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler: Slf4jEventHandler started
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Connecting to BlockManagerMaster: akka://spark@SHXJ-H07-SDB06:38975/user/BlockManagerMaster
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 323.9 MB.
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO storage.DiskStore: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20131220174217-be8e
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 52043 with id = ConnectionManagerId(TS-BH90,52043)
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Connecting to MapOutputTracker: akka://spark@SHXJ-H07-SDB06:38975/user/MapOutputTracker
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-1b1a6c0b-965e-4834-a3d3-554c95442041
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO server.Server: jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
13/12/20 17:42:17 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:41811
13/12/20 17:42:18 ERROR executor.StandaloneExecutorBackend: Driver terminated or disconnected! Shutting down.
```

The log in worker as follows:

```
13/12/19 17:49:26 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20131219174926-0001/2 for SparkHdfsLR
13/12/19 17:49:26 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "java" "-cp" ":/var/bh/spark/conf:/var/bh/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.9.3/spark-assembly-0.8.0-incubating-hadoop1.0.3.jar:/var/bh/spark/core/target/scala-2.9.3/test-classes:/var/bh/spark/repl/target/scala-2.9.3/test-classes:/var/bh/spark/mllib/target/scala-2.9.3/test-classes:/var/bh/spark/bagel/target/scala-2.9.3/test-classes:/var/bh/spark/streaming/target/scala-2.9.3/test-classes" "-Djava.library.path=/var/bh/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.StandaloneExecutorBackend" "akka://spark@SHXJ-H07-SDB06:56158/user/StandaloneScheduler" "2" "TS-BH87" "8"
13/12/19 17:49:30 INFO worker.Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20131219174926-0001/2
13/12/19 17:49:30 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20131219174926-0001/2 interrupted
13/12/19 17:49:30 INFO worker.ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
```

It looks like the worker load is not launched successfully.

I don't know why. Is there anybody that can give me a suggestion?

Comment: Please specify the type of `lines`.

Comment: @senia it's [RDD](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/api/core/spark/RDD.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I update the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it does't work.

Because of some bad configuration, the spark can only work in the standalone mode. correct the configuration, and if you want the code running in distributed mode, the last two parameters must be specific for the function SparkContext:

```
new SparkContext(master, jobName, [sparkHome], [jars])
```

If the last two parameters are not specific, the scala script can only work in standalone mode.